# Previous iphone simulators

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, simulator

I'm trying to find a way to permanently keep previous iphone simulators. Every time I close xcode I need to re install the iphone simulators 5 and 5.1 from the xcode preferences in the download tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had same problem in past time. following procedure solve my problem. Try it if it may help you.

1.) Download all simulator once which you need.

2.) Copy all simulator sdk form `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs`

3.) Paste all sdk on you local disk.

4.) next time when you not found simulator then copy all sdk from where you saved in local disk and paste in to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs`

**This is for try i am not sure that this will work for everyone.**